# Why Mongo is not throwing exception if connecting using different methods?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a problem where I need Mongo to throw exception on time out. The problem is that using this way to create my MongoClient it doesn't throw an exception:

```
String database = "database";
        String username = "myUser;

        String connectionStringValue = "mongodb://" + username + ":" + repository.getPassword() + "@"
                + "myHost" + ":" + "27027" + "/" + database
                + "?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000";

        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(connectionStringValue);

        MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(connectionString);
```

Everything works. I can connect to the database, add documents, etc. But it doesn't throw an exception when there is a timeout situation. Instead it returns a null document.

But if I connect using this way:

```
MongoCredential credential = createCredentials(information);
        ServerAddress serverAdress = new ServerAddress("myHost",
                27027);
        MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().serverSelectionTimeout(10000).build();
        return new MongoClient(serverAdress, credential, options);
```

Then again, everything works but here I get the timeout when expected instead of a null document in response.
I'm wondering what am I missing here in order to make it throw an exception after the time out for the first case. I need to use the first case because there I'm using com.mongodb.client.MongoClient instead of com.mongodb.MongoClient (second case).

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When using connectionString to connect to mongodb, try use the parameter `connectTimeoutMS=10000`
rather then `serverSelectionTimeoutMS=10000` , i would also add a socket timeout: `socketTimeoutMS=10000` , so your full connection uri will be:

```
String connectionStringValue = "mongodb://" + username + ":" + repository.getPassword() + "@"
            + "myHost" + ":" + "27027" + "/" + database
            + "?connectTimeoutMS=10000"
            + "&socketTimeoutMS=10000;
```

this is according to mongodb manual, I hope that's helps.

Comment: yeah, I tried that before, but still not working... Seems like there is some default configuration when using com.mongodb.MongoClient.

Comment: Well then idk, sorry :/